# C# Windows Forms - Beginner Guidance Required - Enabling button only when two text boxes have characters entered

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox, disable

I am designing a program in Visual Studio - Windows Forms c#.net framework to log Gamertags and High Scores of entrants into a gaming competition. I have a textbox for a user to enter a Gamertag and a textbox for a user to enter a High Score, and then a button to log the Gamertag and High Score into a separate two lists.

The issue im having is around disabling the button until both the Gamertag and High Score fields have some text in them. This will be insultingly easy for a lot of you but I am not sure how to write the code to make this happen, I will show what I have:

So on initialise component I have the following:

```
{
    btnAdd.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHighScore.Text);
    btnAdd.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text);
}
```

Button is disabled as soon as the program launches until text is entered.

Then further down I have code on the TextChanged sections of each text box

```
private void txtHighScore_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnAdd.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHighScore.Text);
}

private void txtGamertag_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      btnAdd.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGamertag.Text);           
}
```

From reading this you will see that if text is entered into either box the button will be enabled, but I only want it to be enabled if text has successfully be input into BOTH fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set both textboxes `TextChanged` events to this method called `DataChanged` (you can choose the name you please)

```
private void DataChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnAdd.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtHighScore.Text)
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGamertag.Text);
}
```

As you can see you have to use both checks together to enable button and for this you can take advantage of `&&` which means *and*.
Naturally you could write both events with the same commands, but using just one method for both events makes clear what you're doing and there's only one point in code where you can make changes if necessary, so code is more maintainable.

Your code is not working because you enable/disable button using just one textbox at once.

Comment: Many thanks for this exactly right, I did attempt this at first as I have done in the past however was getting an error for the '&&' and couldnt understand why, was obviously doing something wrong. thanks again!